# Serving a downloadable file without a file extension?

Tags: http, http-headers, attachment, file-extension

I'm using Rails to serve a file to the user like so:

```
def show
  headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"SIGNATURE\""
  headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain"
  render :text => 'some text file content'
end
```

My browser (Chrome on OS X) renames `SIGNATURE` to `SIGNATURE.txt` when downloading.

I have tried several methods such as setting `Content-Type: application/unknown` and putting a `.` after `SIGNATURE`.

How can I ensure that the browser does not attach an extension to the file name?

This is not specifically a Rails question--it most likely a HTTP header response setting I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the content type to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Actually, I think this worked. Just making sure before accepting :)

Comment: After a bit more testing, it does work. There was an issue I was getting, where the server was responding with `304 Not Modified` and not sending the `Content-Type`, even though `Content-Disposition` was being sent.